# Indexing from an ndimensional array - numpy/ python

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with matrices of (x,y,z) dimensions, and would like to index numerous values from this matrix simultaneously.

```
ie. if the index A[0,0,0] = 5

and A[1,1,1] = 10

A[[1,1,1], [5,5,5]] = [5, 10]
```

however indexing like this seems to return huge chunks of the matrix.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I have a large array of indices (n, x, y, z) that i need to use to index from A)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced indexing works like this:

```
A[I, J, K][n] == A[I[n], J[n], K[n]]
```

with `A`, `I`, `J`, and `K` all arrays. That's not the full, general rule, but it's what the rules simplify down to for what you need.

For example, if you want `output[0] == A[0, 0, 0]` and `output[1] == A[1, 1, 1]`, then your `I`, `J`, and `K` arrays should look like `np.array([0, 1])`. Lists also work:

```
A[[0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `1` as the first index 3 times and `5` as the index into the second dimension (again three times). This will give you the element at `A[1,5,:]` repeated *three times*.

```
A = np.random.rand(6,6,6);
B = A[[1,1,1], [5,5,5]]
# [[ 0.17135991,  0.80554887,  0.38614418,  0.55439258,  0.66504806,  0.33300839],
#  [ 0.17135991,  0.80554887,  0.38614418,  0.55439258,  0.66504806,  0.33300839],
#  [ 0.17135991,  0.80554887,  0.38614418,  0.55439258,  0.66504806,  0.33300839]]

B.shape
# (3, 6)
```

Instead, you will want to specify `[1,5]` for *each* axis of your matrix.

```
A[[1,5], [1,5], [1,5]] = [5, 10]
```